# How to Scroll Images Right and Left on FocusChanged in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hi i want to Add Multiple Images on the Horizontal Scroll Field Manager.

Staring Point of the Horizontal Field Manager is Middle of the Screen Horizontally.

Position of Focus image (y coordinate) up form another images.

When Focus Changed from image to right than scroll images Right Side.

If Focus Changed from images to left than scroll images left up to full Width of the Screen Left.

But the Starting Point of Images Middle of the Screen Horizontally.

Here is My Code for that

```
public class MainClass extends MainScreen{
private HorizontalFieldManager hManager;
private HorizontalFieldManager[] hBitmap;
int Height = Display.getHeight();
int Width = Display.getWidth();
private PictureScrollField pictureScrollField;
private String footer_images[] = new String[]
               {"ajtak.jpg","assiant.jpg","astha.jpg","fox_news.jpg",
               "cnbc.jpg","india_news.jpg","zee.jpg"};
private Bitmap [] bitmaps;
private ScrollEntry[] entries;
public MainClass()
{
    hManager = new HorizontalFieldManager()
    {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth,int maxHeight)
        {
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setExtent(Width, 60);
        }


    };

    bitmaps = new Bitmap[footer_images.length];
    entries = new ScrollEntry[footer_images.length];

    for(int i =0; i < footer_images.length;i++)
    {
        bitmaps[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(footer_images[i]);
        entries[i] = new ScrollEntry(bitmaps[i], "", "");

    }

    pictureScrollField = new PictureScrollField(36, 36);

    pictureScrollField.setData(entries, 0);
    pictureScrollField.setImageDistance(38);
    pictureScrollField
            .setHighlightStyle(HighlightStyle.ILLUMINATE);
    pictureScrollField.setHighlightBorderColor(Color.GREEN);

    pictureScrollField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory
            .createSolidTransparentBackground(0x212424, 150));

    pictureScrollField.setLabelsVisible(false);

    pictureScrollField.setFocusListener(new FocusChangeListener() {

        public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {  
            if (pictureScrollField.isFocus()) {

                switch (pictureScrollField.getCurrentImageIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }


        }


    });
    hManager.add(pictureScrollField);
    add(hManager);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    private PictureScrollField _pictureScrollField;     

    ScrollEntry[] entries = new ScrollEntry[ 4 ];
    entries[0] = new ScrollEntry(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image1.jpg"), "BlackBerry", "image 1");
    entries[1] = new ScrollEntry(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image2.jpg"), "Blue logo", "image 2");
    entries[2] = new ScrollEntry(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image3.jpg"), "Black logo", "image 3");
    entries[3] = new ScrollEntry(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image3.jpg"), "Building", "image 4");

    _pictureScrollField = new PictureScrollField(150, 100);
    _pictureScrollField.setData(entries, 0);
    add(_pictureScrollField);
```

Comment: I have Used Picture Scroll Field.But its doesn't solve my Problem.Please Check This link [http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/screenshots/56307/?lang=en] In this Image at bottom show multiple images add. i want to show images like this.

Comment: Hi and I want to Scroll images Right and Left on focus changed. But in Picture Scroll Field images Scroll when i Click on images. But i Want to scroll images on Focus Changed.

Comment: I think i have to Customize (PictureScrollField.setHighlightStyle) of PictureScrollField.But how i dont know can somebody help me.

Comment: One More thing for Reduce Gap (space)Between images Use PictureScrollField.setImageDistance(int gap)? But Its isn't available on OS 6.0 so if you are using OS 5.0 you may be out of luck.